# GetRandomRgn does not exclude tooltip

Tags: winapi, tooltip, gdi

There is `GetRandomRgn( hdc, hrgn, SYSRGN )` to determine window's system clipping region.
When my window is partially covered by other windows I get the correct region.

However, if window that covers my window is a tooltip, it's not subtracted from the region returned by the function.

Any idea why tooltip windows are not excluded and what can I do to exclude them without enumerating all windows myself, determining how they affect my window, etc?

Thank you.

Update: this is on Windows 7 with Aero disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because tooltips are layered windows. Layered windows do not participate in classical occlusion. (One reason is that they have alpha, so occlusion is not a binary concept.) You didn't say why you need this information so there's not much more that can be said beyond "yup."

Comment: My program gets window DC, transforms and outputs it to a bitmap. This is done to all visible windows. Different windows may get different transformations so this is why the program needs to know where one window ends and another begins.

Comment: Shouldn't you be transforming the whole window and not just the visible portion? (For example if you are performing a rotation, then occluded pixels might come into view after rotation.) At any rate, the region returned is at least as big as the actual visible region, so the only damage is that you do a little bit too much work. (Which might actually be the right amount of work if the occluding window has alpha.)

Comment: The whole window is transformed. Then the visible part of the window goes to the output bitmap. So the clipping is important. Anyway, I think I get the idea now, thanks.

Comment: Then draw the transformed tooltip on top of the transformed normal window. You're doing this anyway since you say you are processing all visible windows.